# winshell.shortcut(parent) giving 'module has no attribute 'shortcut'

Tags: python-3.x, windows-7-x64, python-winshell

-Update at the bottom-

pywin32 & winshell installed with no apparent errors, 
but the following test code (extracted from the example here: [winshell examples](https://winshell.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/shortcuts.html#read-details-from-an-existing-shortcut) ):

```
import winshell
parent = 'H:\MUSIC\TESTC\TESTTB.lnk'  # target is H:\MUSIC\TESTB
with winshell.shortcut(parent) as link:
    print(link.path)
```

produced this result:

```
> Python 3.3.0 (v3.3.0:bd8afb90ebf2, Sep 29 2012, 10:57:17) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\MyScripts\Audio\shortcut2.py", line 3, in <module>
    with winshell.shortcut(parent) as link:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'shortcut'
>>>
```

Presumably something must, in fact, not be right with the winshell install - what should I be looking for?

PS:  The system seems to require the output on the python window to be formatted as code which it clearly is not.  Curious as to why.  It does *contain* a code fragment but that's not the same thing.

- update -
  Most of the other methods shown in the docs are not in the dir(winshell) output (eg the file methods such as copy_file):

  ```
  >>> dir(winshell)
  >>> ['__RELEASE__', '__VERSION__', '__builtins__',  
  >>> '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', 
  >>> '__initializing__', '__loader__', '__name__', 
  >>> '__package__', '__path__']
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved after some assistance from [@Maksim Yegorov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5293595/maksim-yegorov).  The problem was that the installation process automatically put the winshell files into 
.../Lib/site-packages/winshell.
However for the example code to work they need to be in 
.../Lib/site-packages
If they are to be in their own folder then instead of
`from winshell import shortcut` its 
`from winshell.winshell import shortcut` and line 26 of winshell.py needs to be modified in like manner to 
`from winshell.__winshell_version__ import __VERSION__`

The winshell docs may need to be clarified to avoid this.